# how to calculate PPU for image sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an image for creating rounded button in unity, but, If I don't account for the correct PPU value, the button gets distorted (I'm even using sliced images):
[image]
Through trial and error, the PPU value of 300 seems to look like the original image:
[image]
but, I don't know a way to confirm if that is correct. How would we actually calculate the PPU value to use for images?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need rounded rectangle image and need to slice it as follow

[image: Sliced image screenshot]

I have sliced the image as shown above and added an `Image` component in scene like following

[image: Image component settings]

Notice the `Pixel per unit multiplier` it is to control the border radius, and now I can stretch the image and it won't get distorted. Check the screenshots for that

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

And for the text I have used `TextMeshProUGUI` as the child of the Image.